# How does the function add_disk_randomness work?

Tags: random, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the `add_disk_randomness` function from the linux kernel. I read a few papers, but they don't describe it very well. This code is from `/drivers/char/random.c`:

```
add_timer_randomness(disk->random, 0x100 + disk_devt(disk));
```

`disk_devt(disk)` holds the variable `disk->devt`. I understand it as a unique block device number. But what are the major and minor device number?

Then the block device number and the hex 0x100 are added together.

Then we collect also the time value `disk->random`. Is this the seek time for each block?

These two values will be passed to the function `add_timer_randomness`. It would be nice to get an example with values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of add_timer_randomness is a pointer to `struct timer_rand_state`. You can confirm this by checking `struct gendisk`.

[`timer_rand_state`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1d61e7fe3760851319138550efb732273ab2e57/drivers/char/random.c#L1071) from random.c is reproduced below

```
/* There is one of these per entropy source */
struct timer_rand_state {
    cycles_t last_time;
    long last_delta, last_delta2;
};
```

This struct stores the timestamp of the last input event as well as previous "deltas". [`add_timer_randomness`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/c1d61e7fe3760851319138550efb732273ab2e57/drivers/char/random.c#L1115) first gets the current time (measured in jiffies), then reads `last_time` (also in jiffies), then overwrites `last_time` with the first value.

The first, second, and third order "deltas" are tracked as a means of estimating entropy. The main source of entropy from hard disk events is the timing of those events. More data is hashed into the entropy pool, but they don't contribute to entropy estimates. (It is important not to over estimate how unpredictable the data you hash in is. Otherwise your entropy pool, and therefore your RNG output too, may be predictable. Underestimating entropy on the other hand cannot make RNG output more predictable. It is always better to use a pessimistic estimator in this respect. That is why data that doesn't contribute to entropy estimates are still hashed into the entropy pool.)

Delta is the time between two events. (The difference between timestamps.) The second order delta is the difference between the times between two events. (Difference between deltas.) Third order deltas is differences between second order deltas. The `timer_rand_state` pointer is the memory location that tracks the previous timestamp and deltas. `delta3` does not need to be stored.

The entropy estimate from this timing data is based on the logarithm of the largest absolute value of deltas one, two, and three. (Not exactly the logarithm. It's always an integer, for example. It's always rounded down by one bit. And if the value you're taking the almost-logarithm of is zero the result is also zero.)

Say you have a device used as an entropy source that generates a new events every 50 milliseconds. The delta will always be 50ms. The second order delta is always zero. Since one of the three deltas is zero this prevents this device's timings from being relied on as a significant entropy source. The entropy estimator successfully fails to overestimate input entropy, so even if this device is used as an entropy source it won't "poison" the entropy pool with predictability.

The entropy estimate isn't based on any formal mathematics. We can't construct an accurate model of the entropy source because we don't know what it is. We don't know what the hardware on a user's computer will be exactly or exactly how it will behave in an unknown environment. We just want to know that if we add one to the (estimated) entropy counter then we've hashed at least one bit of entropy worth of unpredictable data into the entropy pool. Extra data besides just the timings is hashed into the pool without increasing the entropy counter, so we hope that if the timer-based entropy estimator some time over estimates then maybe there is some unpredictability in the non-timer-based source we didn't account for. (And if that's the case your RNG is still safe.)

I'm sure that sounds unconvincing, but I don't know how to help that. I tried my best to explain the relevant parts of the random.c code. Even if I could mind meld and provide some intuition for how the process works it probably would still be unsatisfying.

Comment: "Successfully fails to overestimate" because "succeeds to underestimate" does not mean the same thing. I can succeed in underestimating any positive value by estimating the value to be zero. The goal is **to not overestimate** not **to underestimate**.

Comment: I changed "mind meld" into "mind melt", but I honestly don't know why you need that last section.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Mind meld is a term, though. I don't know what "mind melt" would mean.

Comment: @FutureSecurity Thank very much for the good explaination for ``add_timer_randomness``. But what I still doesn't understand is what the mean the major- and minor-number of the block device and what ``disk->random`` mean.